# Get USB devices without admin privileges

Tags: c#, administration, device

I need to get a list of USB devices plugged in without admin privileges. Unfortunately System.Management.ManagementObjectSearcher requires admin privileges. Is there another way to do this? I only need to see the devices, don't need to disable or enable or do anything fancy.

Comment: Could you impersonate somebody with higher privileges in your code? Unfortunately `ManagementObjectSearcher` is the de facto way for .NET to do what you want.

Comment: Very interesting suggestion... Never heard of this until now. After reading into it, it seems that admin username and passwords will need to be known. It will unfortunately not be possible, but very interesting indeed. Thanks

Comment: There's no requirement that you use the "administrator" account, any account that is part of the administrators group would work. Is this an app that's going to be deployed somewhere where you don't have control over the users? You could employ UAC here and ask for elevated permissions when the application runs (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756929.aspx), or impersonate a domain or dedicated service account that is a built-in administrator

Comment: Thanks for your help Cory... I will be going with your UAC suggestion.  Seems the least painful! :-)